# Update denormalized data in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, denormalization, nosql

Let's say, we have users who can comment videos and we want to show all comments by video with user's name.
Also user may go to his profile page and change his name.

Based on Cassandra data modeling practices that was covered in this answer [Cassandra denormalization datamodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281536/cassandra-denormalization-datamodel), I've create such tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   user_id UUID,
   first_name TEXT,
   last_name TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY ((user_id))
); 

CREATE TABLE comments_by_video (
   video_id UUID,
   added_at TIMESTAMP,
   user_id UUID,
   comment TEXT,
   first_name TEXT,
   last_name TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY ((video_id), added_at, user_id)
);
```

Looks awesome, we can get data that needed to show comments by video just by one query.

Now, let's consider such use case.

User created a lot of comments (like 10 000) and then decided to change his name.
Should we update all comments to change his name?
Is there a way to make it efficient?

Comment: Have you gained more insight on the issue? I denormalized my comments like in here and I wonder what happens if user changes them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Congratulation, you just enter the relationnal database zone !

More seriously, this requirement is a pain with your model. Either you have to use the `user_id` to query `last_name` and `first name` in `users` table for every comments at reads, or you need to look accross all partitions and all comments to replace the `first_name` and `last_name` everywhere. There is no way to make it efficient.

However, let's try a naive approach. You could create a users table, a videos table and another table that store all comments of a user like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE users_videos_comment(
    user_id uuid,
    video_id uuid,
    time timestamp,
    comment text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((user_id,video_id), time)
);
```

This is efficient for your new requirement, for a user and a video you can get all comments, so you just have to query users to look for the name, but you loose the "one query for all comments in a video". Also, you have to store in `users` a list of video where a user commented and on `videos` a list of users that made comments. This is difficult to maintain and will ask some more code.

There are maybe better ways to do it, but remember with noSQL **What you loose on writes, you gain on reads**

If you don't mind doing a lot of writes to change the username, then keep it as it is. From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422181/cassandra-good-for-write-and-less-read-hbase-random-read-write), Cassandra seems better for writes anyway, so you should think of optimizing the reads.

With that in mind, we can add a field in `users` that list all comments made by a user. This way, you won't have to scan across `comments_by_video` to look for every comments made by a user. This add some complexity because for any comments made by a user, you have to make two writes (**and make sure it is consistent**). But you have both requirements satisfied.

Hope it helps

Comment: it doesn't suit you?

Comment: Yea, I've already thought these options. In case with `users_videos_comment`, we have `n + 1` problem, so if video was commented by 1000 different users, then we will make 1000 + 1000 + 1 (or just 1000 + 1 in case we don't store name in the `comments_by_video`).
`videos_where_user_made_comment` or store comments/videos in `users` table seems like most efficient way for now.

Comment: sorry, I've deleted my previous comments, since I can't edit it.

Comment: did you look at the second way? where you list in the video all users that commented? That way you can retrieve the comments on a video with `users_that_comment

Comment: Well, if I understood correctly. First, select list of users that made comment by video. Second, loop over list and get comments. In this case, we make `n + 1` queries, where `n` number of users that made comment. So, worst case will be when a lot of users just made one comment.

Comment: yeah. In your case, you would have to read the whole partition to change the name on the comment which would be a pain.